# AlertDialog show() Causes Exception

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

I get this error when I press the back button when my `ProgressDialog` is running:

```
08-25 17:00:41.058  28731-28731/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@419e2088 is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:664)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.InfoBookActivity$LoadPlants.onPostExecute(InfoBookActivity.java:315)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.InfoBookActivity$LoadPlants.onPostExecute(InfoBookActivity.java:291)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And these are the significant snippets of my code:

```
     ProgressDialog pDialog;
     android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_infobook);
        // Load the plants via AsyncTask
        new LoadPlants().execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        dismissProgressDialog();
        dismissAlertDialog();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public class LoadPlants extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showProgressDialog("Acquiring data from the Internet. Please wait.");
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            if (!CheckConnection.isConnectionOnline()) {
                return false;
            }
            updateJSONData();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (InfoBookActivity.this.isFinishing())
                return;
            dismissProgressDialog();
            if (result == false) {
                alert = new CheckConnection().showConnectionFailureDialogBox(InfoBookActivity.this);
                alert.show();
                return;
            }
            updateList();
        }
    }

    public void showProgressDialog(String message) {
        if (pDialog == null) {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(InfoBookActivity.this);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            pDialog.show();
        }
        pDialog.setMessage(message);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    public void dismissProgressDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void dismissAlertDialog() {
        if (alert != null && alert.isShowing()) {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

And this is `Line 315`: `alert.show();`

Basically, a `ProgressDialog` called `pDialog` will pop up to tell the user that its fetching data from the net. I want this `ProgressDialog` to be cancelable (when the user presses the back button, the activity closes and screen goes **back to the previous activity**) but I'm getting this exception. But I'm not supposed to. I mean, the `alert.show()` shouldn't be called since I've to kill this activity. BTW, I'm testing my app offline. If there's no connection and the user didn't cancel the `ProgressDialog`, the app should show the `AlertDialog` called `alert`. But in my case, it was cancelled.

I've tried creating an object for my `AsyncTask` and not just calling on its default constructor to create an instance, and calling the `cancel(true)` method for it in my `ProgressDialog` listener, but I get the same error.

Declared and initialized it like this: `LoadPlants loadPlants = new LoadPlants();`

And somewhere in the `onCreate()` method: `loadPlants.execute();`

And the `ProgressDialog`'s cancel listener set to this:

```
pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                loadPlants.cancel(true);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

I'm having issues with leaks and stuff. I'm trying to fix it. If you think there's any more way I could get a leak, please tell me where and what I should do. Thanks.

Additionally:

```
public AlertDialog showConnectionFailureDialogBox(final Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.str_dialogBoxMessage);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.str_dialogBoxOkButton,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    ((Activity) context).finish();
                }
            });
    builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            ((Activity) context).finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    return alert;
}
```

Comment: Sorry 'bout the earlier misleading title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object of `LoadPlanet` and cancel it when your activity closes. 
`OnPostExecute` will not be called after calling cancel.

e.g.
start your task like this:

```
LoadPlanet loadPlanetTask = new LoadPlanet();
loadPlanetTask.execute();
```

End it like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    loadPlanetTask.cancel(true);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's been difficult for me to handle these leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the `finish()` from your code and see if it fixes the issue.

If it does, look for the sequence of execution, it may be the case that your `Activity` is getting finished before your dialog is being shown.

Comment: Indeed, it is. I finished the activity whilst not canceling the `AsynTask`.